# Firebase Crashlytics: Upload dSYM script blocks iOS app building and archiving

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, crashlytics, dsym

I integrated **Firebase Crashlytics** in one of my **bitcode disabled iOS project**. It's working properly if I remove upload dSYM script(see image 2). But if add it then app building process never get complete same thing happens for app archiving also.
I integrated Firebase Crashlytics in some other projects as well and all are working properly and used same configuration and scripts but only this app have issue.

**Project Configuration -**

1. Crashlytics version - 4.6.2
2. My project minimum deployment target - iOS 12
3. XCode version - 12.5 and Xcode 13

I checked my app bundle identifier it is proper in `GoogleService-Info.plist`. And path of `GoogleService-Info.plist` is also correct in script.

I have following scripts -:

Script 1.
[image]

Script 2.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Updated **Crashlytics version from 4.6.2 to latest version 8.8.0**. It solved the issue. But still I could not find any reason why older 4.6.2 is working in other projects but not working in only one project.